# Tar.exe can't add 2 files from different folders

Tags: cmd, zip, tar

I am trying to add 2 different files to a zip-archive using tar.exe.
The folder structure is as follows:

- RootFolder

  - SubDirectory1

    - File1.txt
  - SubDirectory2

    - SubDirectory3

      - File2.txt
  - SubDirectory4

    - File3.txt
    - File4.txt

I'd like to add File1, File2 and all Files of SubDirectory4 to the archive with relative paths.

The command which I am using is while the current directory is RootFolder:
`tar.exe -cf archive.zip -C SubDirectory1 File1.txt -C SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3 File2.txt SubDirectory4`

After executing it gives the following error: `tar.exe: could not chdir to 'SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3'`
I couldn't find similiar problems or neither was the documentation of the -C flag good enough for me to understand the problem.
Does anyone have an idea why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `cd`'d into `SubDirectory1` that became the current directory within the command, so in order to `cd` into `SubDirectory3\Subdirectory4` you need to make that relative to `SubDirectory1` not the original directory. Then when you `cd` into `SubDirectory4`, that will need to be relative to `SubDirectory3`.

Given the above, and with `RootFolder` as your current directory, try this instead:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\tar.exe -cf "archive.zip" -C ".\SubDirectory1" "File1.txt" -C "..\SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3" "File2.txt" -C "..\..\SubDirectory4" "File3.txt" "File4.txt"
```

If you wanted the entire content of `SubDirectory4` then change the last glob accordingly:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\tar.exe -cf "archive.zip" -C ".\SubDirectory1" "File1.txt" -C "..\SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3" "File2.txt" -C "..\..\SubDirectory4" "*"
```

*I have used double-quotes here as best practice, although in the case of the provided file and directory names you've used, those can be omitted if preferred. I have also used the full path and extension to the default Windows 10 version of `tar.exe`, if you do not care about robust code, and wish to gamble that the `%Path%` and `%PATHEXT%` variables have not been corrupted, then feel free to change `%SystemRoot%\System32\tar.exe` to `tar`.*

Answer (score 1):

**Compo has shown correctly** how -C can navigate relative to the Arc to store without folders, and thus **his is the correct answer** to the Original Posed Question

```
>tar -tf archive.zip

File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
File4.txt
```

However for those that are looking how to store files relative to the root Arc

use this method or variation
remember to use **"double quotes" for spaces**, either for "path name/file name"

**NOTE a tar file is NOT a Zip** so **by default** should never use that extension. *I am correcting myself since tar can build a valid zip file. see later*
[image]

Always name the archive in a meaning full way here I use root to show pedigree and **.tar** to indicate how it may be extracted.

```
tar -f root.tar -c SubDirectory1\File1.txt SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3\File2.txt SubDirectory4\*.*
```

on later extraction the subfolders and their contents will be preserved relative to the root

```
>tar -tf root.tar

SubDirectory1/File1.txt
SubDirectory2/SubDirectory3/File2.txt
SubDirectory4/File3.txt
SubDirectory4/File4.txt
```

### Post scriptum

It may be interesting to know, Tar can build a valid.zip and can list and extract them. (note the difference in reporting contents).

```
>tar -tf root.zip

SubDirectory1/File1.txt
SubDirectory2/SubDirectory3/
SubDirectory2/SubDirectory3/File2.txt
SubDirectory4/File3.txt
SubDirectory4/File4.txt
```

We can extract those subfolder simply (**and without visible feedback**)

```
errorlevel 0 All files were processed successfully.
errorlevel 1 An error occurred.
```

using >`tar -xf root.zip`

**To build a zip file we need to add the -auto switch**

```
tar -a -f root.zip -c SubDirectory1\File1.txt SubDirectory2\SubDirectory3\File2.txt SubDirectory4\*.*
```

[image]

Comment: `tar -acf StackMeFirst.zip -c manifest.json background.js contentScript.js Icons` this command worked for me in Windows 10