# Dowloading files as a single .zip on windows server

Tags: windows, download, zip

a client have a download area where users can download or browse single files. Files are divided in folder, so there are documents, catalogues, newsletter and so on, and their extension can vary: they can be .pdf, .ai or simple .jpeg. He asked me if I can provide a link to download every item in a specific folder as a big, compressed file. Problem is, I'm on a Windows server, so I'm a bit clueless if there's a way. I can edit pe pages of this area, so I can include jquery and scripts with a little freedom. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Windows archiver is TAR and you are needing to build a **TAR**b**ALL** (Historically all related files in one Tape ARchive)

I have a file server which is mapped as S:\ (it does not have TAR command, and Tar cannot use URL but can use device:)

For any folders contents (including sub folders) it is easy to remotely save all current files in a zip with a single command (for multiple root locations they need a loop or a list)

[image]

It will build the Tape Archive as a windows.zip using the -a (auto) switch but you need to consider the desired level of nesting by collect all contents at the desired root location.

[image]

`TAR -a[other options] file.zip [folder / files]`

Points to watch out for

- ensure here is not an older archive
- it will comment error/warnings like the two given during run, however, should complete without fail.

Once you have the zip file you can offer post as a web asset such as
`<a href="\\server\folder\all.zip" download="all.zip">Get All<a>`

for other notes see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728992/10802527